# How to map key and value from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following JSON response via $http:

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "prices": [
                {
                    "2015": 2
                },
                {
                    "2014": 3
                },
                {
                    "2013": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "prices": [
                {
                    "2015": 1
                },
                {
                    "2014": 3
                },
                {
                    "2013": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a map function (or several functions) in Javascript so that I can get the following 2 sets:

```
$scope.new_data = [
    {
        name: 'apple',
        data: [5,3,2]
    },
    {
        name: 'banana',
        data: [4,3,1]
    }
]
```

and

```
$scope.years = ['2013','2014','2015']
```

Perhaps something like this… but I don't know how to separate the key from the value:

```
$scope.new_data = $scope.fruits.map(function(fruit){
    return {
        name: fruit.name,
        data: fruit.prices
    };
});

$scope.years = $scope.fruits.map(function(fruit){
    return [
        fruit.prices.reverse();
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all in one `.map` function

```
var formattedData = data.fruits.map(function(fruit) {
    return {
        name: fruit.name,
        data: fruit.prices.map(function(price) {
            return price[Object.keys(price)[0]];
        }).reverse()
    }
});

var years = [];
var allYears = data.fruits.map(function(fruit) {
    //Get all years to 2d array
    return fruit.prices.map(function(price) {
        return Object.keys(price)[0];
    });
}).reduce(function(p, c) {
    //Flatten 2d array
    return p.concat(c)
}, []);

//Remove duplicates
allYears.forEach(function(year) {
    if (years.indexOf(year) === -1) {
        years.push(year);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, that works for the data! How about the array of years?

Comment: That gives: ['2015','2014','2013','2015','2014','2013'] I think it's looping twice and also needs to be reversed

Comment: @murid -- Check the `years` variable - it should get rid of the duplicates.